# Casting a Parent to a Child object in C#

Tags: c#, casting

Lets say I have a parent class User as follows

```
class User{
  int Id {get;set;}
  UserType Type {get;set;}
  //More properties
}
```

Then I have two child objects

```
class Employer : User
{
    // UserType should always be employer
   //some methods and properties
}

class JobSeeker : User
{
    // UserType should always be JobSeeker
   //some methods and properties

}
```

There are times when I am given an Id and I query the db and load the user. But depending upon whether the user is an employer or job seeker I want to do different things.

The way I do it right now is as follows:

```
userRepository.TryLoad(userId, out user) 

if (user.UserType == UserType.Employer) 
{
     //do some stuff
}
else if (user.UserType == UserType.JobSeeker) 
{
    // do some other stuff
}
```

I was wondering if I could do somethings like the following:

```
userRepository.TryLoad(userId, out user)

 if (user is Seeker) 
{
   //do some other stuff
}
else if (user is Employer) 
{    
   //do some stuff
}
```

Edit ===

If my userRepository.TryLoad() gives me a user with user.UserType = UserType.Employer, if I use

```
var employer = user as Employer
```

employer is always null.

=== Edit 2====

User defined conversion seems to be a way I could go but then "as" and "is" keywords do not work for User defined conversions

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx

Comment: Have you tried it to see if you got expected results? Also, this isn't related to casting. Casting would be if you did something like `Employer newEmployer = (Employer)user;`.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I assume `if (user is Seeker)` should be `if (user is JobSeeker) `

Comment: Based on the edited-in info, this is not (primarily) a question of casting, it's a question of storing various child types in the DB and retrieving them. Right now, you're retrieving them only as `User` type.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider creating a common abstract method on User and have each subclass extend it to perform the specific Seeker/Employer behavior. That way you don't have to worry about what subtype you have.

In general if you need to worry about what type of object you have under the hood (e.g., which child class) this is a design smell, and you should consider refactoring your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `TryLoad` is actually giving you instances of `JobSeeker` or `Employer`, yes, you could do something like this:

```
userRepository.TryLoad(userId, out user)

if (user is JobSeeker) 
{
   var jobSeeker = (JobSeeker)user;
   //do some other stuff
} // etc
```

Or as a different style and to avoid checking the type twice, use `as` instead of `is`.

```
userRepository.TryLoad(userId, out user)

var jobSeeker = user as JobSeeker;
if (jobSeeker != null) 
{
   //do some other stuff
} // etc
```